# Meaning and origin of "country" in Oil Country Tubular Goods

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

> [Oil Country Tubular Goods](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/oil-country-tubular-goods-OCTG.html#ixzz495ps7xZl): Pipe and tube products used in petroleum industry, such as drill pipe, pipe casings, oil pipes.

Why "Country"? What does it mean here? How did it originate?

I would understand "country" if the term concerned some particular company, proud of its land of origin (say, Texas) and thus using this "X country" construction. But since it refers to piping made all over the globe..

Comment: It means "region where X is produced or where X is prevalent".  Tobacco country. Oil country. Tornado country. Hillbilly country. Horse country.

Comment: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/barbara-barton-sloane/a-visit-to-kentuckys-hors_b_5617296.html

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=rbchAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA571&dq=%22tobacco+country%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8oOPD8OXMAhUDWT4KHR-oBlQQ6AEIazAO#v=onepage&q=%22tobacco%20country%22&f=false

Comment: @TRomano I think that's the answer! FWIW, it's defined in my [favorite dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/country) as well: "4
[uncountable] an area that is known for a particular product, activity, person, etc."

Comment: @TRomano - so it's there to conjure up the image of an "oil country"? An imaginary country. Because such piping can be produced worldwide.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=7ZQrAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA488&dq=%22indian+country%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjhhfq-8eXMAhWLaT4KHZFrATYQ6AEIYDAL#v=onepage&q=%22indian%20country%22&f=false

Comment: Think of **country** here as "territory" or "region" not as  a political entity. Compare "back-country".

Comment: `{X} country" is a very common phrase in American English. Watch your step, this is snake country.  Don't leave food around, this is bear country.

Comment: @TRomano - I understand this. However, this piping is produced from China to Argentina, as far as I understand, and this confused me.

Comment: The phrase does not assert any sort of uniqueness. There is more than one place in the world where bears are found. But they are certainly found here, because this is bear country. And do not think of it as a political entity. It does not refer to politics or sovereignty, but to a geographic region.

Comment: It seems to have been in used since at least 1859: http://books.google.com/books?id=xUsSAQAAMAAJ&q="oil+country+goods"

Comment: Earlier than that. One of the citations I gave above was from 1777.

Comment: This use of **country** to mean "region, area, territory" goes back to the early 14th century.

Comment: As mentioned above, it should mean "a specific region or territorial space". Check out the definition 3 in the [Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/country) .

Comment: Attestations from 1425 and 1450 of "mountain country" (*monteyne contre*) and "marsh country" (*marsh contrey*), respectively.

Comment: @TRomano - I wanted to know why there's "Country" in that expression

Comment: @CowperKettle: I do not understand your lack of understanding here. "Country" means "region". It is similar to **land** semantically.

Comment: @TRomano I think the OP wants to know why it is not "Oil **Industry** Tubular Goods". I think the term is wrong and doesn't look standard.

Comment: If that's the term that is used by the industry, that's the way it is.

Comment: In America, it is not uncommon to refer to a region by one of its predominant characteristics, especially if the entire local or regional economy is founded on it.   "I grew up in tobacco country".   "My friend, don't talk solar or wind-energy around here. This is oil country."

Comment: @Rathony: it is not an industry-specific locution.  But I cannot speak for somebody's web dictionary. Anyone can put anything on the web.

Comment: Okay, let it remain a mystery.

Comment: I once met an American in Peru who would say things like _"I'm on a fast train to flavor country"_ when she was eating food she liked.

Comment: @MarkHubbard - the mystery is not the overall meaning, it's the presence of "country" there. That hardly makes easier to understand for a Russian drill worker, say, who knows English at the school level and tries to interpret everything word-by-word. International abbreviations are usually more comprehensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems likely the item  to be asking about is not *country* but *oil country*...

"Oil Country" in OCTG could refer/allude to (a) a nation that produces oil; (b) a region called 'oil country', as outlined  in the bulk of this answer *eg* the original Oil Country centered in Pennsylvania; (c)  all such oil countries, in the sense of either *a* or *b*; (d)  perhaps to some original company or market called Oil Country Tubular Goods; (e) anywhere where the oil industry is present, kind of like  [Boston Nation](https://www.instagram.com/boston.nation.sports/) refers to fans of Boston sports teams no matter where they live; (f)   something else.

I've emailed the [American Petroleum Institute](http://www.api.org)  and asked. It's website says standardization of oil field equipment didn't begin to after World War I.

One definition of *country* is

> A region, territory, or large tract of land distinguishable by features of topography, biology, or culture: *hill country; Bible country*.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=country)

Thus, *oil country* refers to any "region, territory, or large tract of land" characterized by the presence of oil or  petroleum (which literally means "rock oil") and the industries,  services, goods, and indeed the wealth and even culture that develops from the extraction, collection, transportation and sale of  crude oil.

In the USA, and I think in the English-speaking world, the original *oil country* (once referred to as *the oil country* because it was so specific & famous a region<sup>1</sup>)  was that portion of northern and western Pennsylvania, etc, including the  *Oil  Creek Valley* (where once American Indians would collect surface oil), which saw 
 the [Pennsylvania Oil Boom/Rush](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennsylvania_oil_rush) after Edwin Drake drilled the first successful well in 1859.

Since then, both in the USA and elsewhere, other *oil countries* have arisen, including parts of Texas and California. There's one in

Note that some place called *oil country* can also be called *something else country* if the same region has more than one defining characteristic: a place could be  oil country, hill country, cattle country, beer country,  redneck country, Willie Nelson country, etc., all at the same time.  Yes, I'm still thinking of Texas.

Also, note that very often, banks, stores, restaurants, parks, zoos, pretty much anything,  will call themselves after the characteristic of where they are located. So you can find *Oil Country Federal Credit Reserve* in Pennsylvania.

Thus, *oil country* refers first and foremost to a geographic location. Perhaps its usage in *Oil Country  Tubular Goods* is allusion to one of these physical regions, maybe to all of them.

Somehow, and I don't know when, where, and why, the term  *Oil Country  Tubular Goods* (OCTG)  came to be applied to certain  goods used anywhere and everywhere in the petroleum industry.

The purported [1859 usage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="oil+country+tubular+goods"+#q=%22oil+country+tubular+goods%22&tbs=sbd:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks) seems specious, some kind of scanning error. The language is not that of the mid-19th century and there is no other usage recorded in Google Books  of the term until the early 1970s.

---

<sup>1 See, for example, "The Oil Country and Its People" in *[Magazine of Western History, 1885](https://books.google.com/books?id=DOE6AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA230&dq=oil+country&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi126X1_uXMAhXDayYKHRWuANkQ6AEIIDAB#v=snippet&q=%22the%20oil%20country%22&f=false)*.</sup>

Comment: Good answer, Alan! OCTG is an industry standard term. For instance, "Oil country tubular goods (OCTG) is a family of seamless rolled products consisting of drill pipe, casing and tubing subjected to loading conditions according to their specific application." This is from the International Molybdenum Association. If you Google OCTG or Oil Country Tubular Goods you will find numerous references to it. It's not necessarily mysterious; it's just what they call it in the oil industry.

Comment: Yes, @MarkHubbard but why? That is a  mystery to me. There's no industry standard  *Cattle Country Beef Products* that refers to some national or international standard.

Comment: I agree with most of the answer except the mentioning that the 1859 usage seems to be some kind of error. It doesn't look like an error to me.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Yes, that's what I was wondering about. It's strange to spread an English construction like this to make people across the world scratch their heads upon reading the word "Country". It's an international standard, shouldn't it be neutral and comprehensible? We can go the whole hog and create global standards like, say, Willly Wonka Web Specifications, or Doctor Zeus Dentistry Code. That will be a head-scratcher.

Comment: *Country* in OCTG  could refer to *an oil producing nation*; I've updated my answer.

Comment: My maternal grandfather was an oilman in Oklahoma. The State Capitol has an oil well on its front lawn. From Wikipedia: "The state capitol complex is famous for its oil wells and remains the only state capitol grounds in the United States with active oil rigs. The capitol building is directly atop the Oklahoma City Oil Field." Like Texas, Pennsylvania, California, Alaska, parts of Canada and many others, Oklahoma is definitely *oil country.* :-) BTW, the 1885 article by A. R. Baker in the *Magazine of Western History* is informative and a wonderful slice of 19th Century Americana. Good find.